# Git error when uploading from local to remote

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code, file-upload

I am uploading a deep learning code to GitHub so my supervisor can take a look at , the total folder size is 17 GB including the data , I have seen examples like this on GitHub before.

```
PS C:\Users\Admin\Heart_project\Heart_segmentation> git push origin main --force
Enumerating objects: 908, done.
Counting objects: 100% (908/908), done.
Delta compression using up to 16 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (899/899), done.
error: RPC failed; HTTP 500 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 500
send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
Writing objects: 100% (908/908), 3.22 GiB | 2.42 MiB/s, done.
Total 908 (delta 363), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

I was expecting that the my project would be uploaded but it keeps stopping I tried many ways, like using the desktop app.

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/working-with-files/managing-large-files/about-large-files-on-github "We recommend repositories remain small, ideally less than 1 GB, and less than 5 GB is strongly recommended. […] If your repository excessively impacts our infrastructure, you might receive an email from GitHub Support asking you to take corrective action." Additionally, "GitHub blocks files larger than 100 MB."

Answer (score 1):

You're probably running up against repository / file size limits.

The size limits on GitHub at the time of this writing are as follows:

[File Size Limits](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/working-with-files/managing-large-files/about-large-files-on-github#file-size-limits):

> GitHub limits the size of files allowed in repositories. If you attempt to add or update a file that is larger than 50 MB, you will receive a warning from Git. The changes will still successfully push to your repository, but you can consider removing the commit to minimize performance impact.
>
> GitHub blocks files larger than 100 MB.
>
> To track files beyond this limit, you must use Git Large File Storage (Git LFS). For more information, see ["About Git Large File Storage."](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/working-with-files/managing-large-files/about-git-large-file-storage)

[Repository Size Limits](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/working-with-files/managing-large-files/about-large-files-on-github#repository-size-limits):

> We recommend repositories remain small, ideally less than 1 GB, and less than 5 GB is strongly recommended. Smaller repositories are faster to clone and easier to work with and maintain. If your repository excessively impacts our infrastructure, you might receive an email from GitHub Support asking you to take corrective action. We try to be flexible, especially with large projects that have many collaborators, and will work with you to find a resolution whenever possible. You can prevent your repository from impacting our infrastructure by effectively managing your repository's size and overall health. You can find advice and a tool for repository analysis in the [`github/git-sizer`](https://github.com/github/git-sizer) repository.

[With Git LFS](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/working-with-files/managing-large-files/about-git-large-file-storage#about-git-large-file-storage):

> | Product | Maximum file size |
> | --- | --- |
> | GitHub Free | 2 GB |
> | GitHub Pro | 2 GB |
> | GitHub Team | 4 GB |
> | GitHub Enterprise Cloud | 5 GB |
>
> If you exceed the limit of 5 GB, any new files added to the repository will be rejected silently by Git LFS.

If your repository contains data files that can be perfectly regenerated from other tracked files in a reasonable amount of time, then don't commit them to your repo (gitignore them and regenerate them after cloning / pulling). If they can't be perfectly regenerated from other tracked files in a reasonable amount of time and you can't fit them within those GitHub limits, then find some other way to share those files to your supervisor. Also compress them for sharing if you haven't already done so and they can be reasonably compressed (are not completely random data).

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the Github documentation:

> [About large files on
> GitHub](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/working-with-files/managing-large-files/about-large-files-on-github)
>
> GitHub limits the size of files allowed in repositories. If you
> attempt to add or update a file that is larger than 50 MB, you will
> receive a warning from Git.
>
> GitHub blocks files larger than 100 MB.
>
> To track files beyond this limit, you must use Git Large File Storage
> (Git LFS). For more information, see "[About Git Large File
> Storage](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/working-with-files/managing-large-files/about-git-large-file-storage)."

Unfortunately, GitHub LFS isn't going to help you with a 17GB upload, either:

> Using Git LFS, you can store files up to:
>
> ```
>               Maximum 
> Product       file size
> -------       ---------
> GitHub Free   2 GB
> GitHub Pro    2 GB
> GitHub Team   4 GB
> GitHub Enterprise Cloud   5 GB
> ```

SUGGESTION: try uploading your "data" to cloud storage ([AWS S3](https://aws.amazon.com/pm/serv-s3), [MS OneDrive](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/onedrive/online-cloud-storage), [Google Drive](https://www.google.com/drive/), etc) and simply *link* to your data in the Git project itself.